# How to create a dynamically updating HistogramBasedTracker in Matlab

Tags: histogram, matlab-cvst, video-tracking

I'm trying to track a basketball in a video file in Matlab. The HistogramBasedTracker class only allows the search histogram of pixel values to be initialized once. I would like to dynamically update the histogram values each time the ball is found in a new frame.

Does anyone know how to do that? I see on the HistogramBasedTracker reference page that the ObjectHistogram property is tunable, but I don't understand what that means. Please help.

Source: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.histogrambasedtrackerclass.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `initializeObject()` multiple times.